# Regex to extract method names from file using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to make some changes inside a lot of files, thus I am writing a `Ruby` script that will open all those files and make the changes. I have worked everything out, but need help with just 1 `Regex` to find all of the methods with particular annotations, as these files are from Java.

Example part of file:

```
...

@Test(priority = 10)
@RunAsClient
public void methodName(){
   ...
}

...

@Test(priority = 20)
public void otherMethodName(){
   ...
}

...
```

I need to find all of these methods, that have this kind of annotations.
Result should be:

`result = ['methodName', 'otherMethodName']`

I can extract one or other, but not both. To extract first kind I've created a regex.

`first_regex_pattern = /(?<=@Test\(priority = \d\d\)\n@RunAsClient\npublic void )([^\(]+)/`

[first regex](https://regex101.com/r/vT5wR7/1)

and to extract second type

`second_regex_pattern = /(?<=@Test\(priority = \d\d\)\npublic void )([^\(]+)/`

[second regex](https://regex101.com/r/yG8xO7/1)

I need to combine my solutions

Comment: There is a common (abbreviated) word regex, and Ruby class `Regexp`, but there is no such thing as `Regex` in Ruby.

Comment: this might be a useful script to change multiple files programmatically: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/ahlen/bin/replace_string -- it's not Ruby, but works very well

Comment: Why don't you just use the Java Annotation Processing libraries, a Java IDE, or a programmatic Java Refactoring tool, which actually understands Java code and Java annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str =<<_
@Test(priority =10)
@RunAsClient
public void metodName(){
   ...
}

   ...

@Test(priority =     20)
public void otherMethodName(){
   ...
}
...
_

r = /
    \@Test\(\s*priority\s*=\s*\d+\s*\)\s*\n  # Match string
    (?:\@RunAsClient\n)?  # Optionally match string
    (?:\w+\s+)+           # Match (word, >= 1 spaces) >= 1 times
    \K                    # Forget everything matched so far
    \w+                   # match word
    (?=                   # begin positive lookahead
      (?:\([^)]*\)\s*\{)  # match paren-enclosed expression, >= 0 spaces, {
      |                   # or
      (?:\s*\{)           # match >= 0 spaces, {
    )                     # end positive lookahead
    /x                    # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan r
  #=> ["metodName", "otherMethodName"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.scan /(@Test\(priority = \d{2}\)\n)?(@RunAsClient\n)?(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)/
#⇒ [
#  [0] [
#    [0] "@Test(priority = 10)\n",
#    [1] "@RunAsClient\n",
#    [2] "public void metodName"
#  ],
#  [1] [
#    [0] "@Test(priority = 20)\n",
#    [1] nil,
#    [2] "public void otherMethodName"
#  ]
# ]
```

For the result requested:

```
str.scan(/(@Test\(priority = \d{2}\)\n)?(@RunAsClient\n)?(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)/)
   .map(&:last)
   .map { |e| e.split(' ').last }                         
#⇒ [
#  [0] "metodName",
#  [1] "otherMethodName"
# ]
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem:  `"life is good".scan /(@Test\(priority = \d{2}\)\n)?(@RunAsClient\n)?(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)/ 
 #=> [[nil, nil, "life is good"]]`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure, there are many glitches with this approach; I assumed the input is strictly defined, and I answered the question “how to to combine my solutions.”

Answer (score 0):

mudasobwa's answer looks great, but in case your functions can have just a type, without the keyword `public`, the regex should be:

```
str.scan(/(@Test\(priority = \d{2}\)\n)?(@RunAsClient\n)?\w+\s+(\w+\s+)?(\w+)/).map(&:last)
```

This is also a bit shorter

And if you're only interested in the function names, but not the data from the context lines, then this regular expression is much simpler -- it matches the signature of a function definition:

```
 str.scan(/\w+\s+(\w+\s+)?(\w+)\(\)\s?\{/).map(&:last)
```

this looks for type, method name, and `()` followed by optional space, and then a `{`

Comment: If `r` is your first regex, `"life is good".scan r #=> ["good"]`. The second may match a string in a line following the line `@Bugaboo`, rather than `@Test...` or `@RunAsClient`, which I believe the OP wants to avoid.